# App engine Blobstore self.get_uploads() empty

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, blobstore, flask-restful

I have integrated the [blobstore example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Complete_Sample_App) into my own code and found that I cannot get it to work properly. The image gets uploaded (it's in the database) but the line `upload = self.get_uploads()[0]` doesn't work since `self.get_uploads()` is empty

Here's my code:

```
class ImageCreate(Resource):
    def get(self):
        form = ImageCreateForm()
        return render_template('images/create.html', form=form, upload_url=blobstore.create_upload_url('/admin/upload')))

class PhotoUploadHandler(Resource, BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        try:
            upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
            form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.get_json())
            image =Image(title=form.title.data, blob_key=upload.key(), notes=form.notes.data)
            image.put()
            redirect('/admin/image/list')
        except():
            redirect('/admin/image/list')

api.add_resource(ImageCreate, '/admin/images/create', endpoint='image_create')
api.add_resource(PhotoUploadHandler, '/admin/upload', endpoint='image_upload')

class Image(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    blob_key = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()
    notes = ndb.StringProperty()
    date_added = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


class ImageCreateForm(Form):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    notes = TextAreaField('Notes')


<form action="{{ upload_url }}" method="post" name="create-image" enctype=multipart/form-data>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div> {{ form.title }}</div>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <div> {{ form.notes }}</div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, after searching and trying a LOT. And visiting a bunch of obscure website that promise answers (most do not) I finally found why this doesn't work... Apparently the `self.get_uploads()` is `webapp2` specific. If one uses flask, another approach is necessary.

To get the current uploaded file, the easiest way is to access the request directly and extract the blob-key from the headers, like so:

```
class PhotoUploadHandler(Resource, BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        try:
            f = request.files['file']
            header = f.headers['Content-Type']
            parsed_header = parse_options_header(header)
            blob_key = parsed_header[1]['blob-key']
```

This effectively does the same as (and replaces) the `self.get_uploads()` function and can be used with flask. Notice that I extend from both `Resource` and `BlobstoreUploadHandler` since I'm using `flask-restfull`. Using only flask one only needs to extend from `BlobstoreUploadHandler`.